# how to use win32com.mapi get new email from outlook in python?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I wanna get a message when a new email into outlook.
I try to use python.

I can find that folders,but can't find the way to get the number of new email.

```js
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
accounts = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.Accounts;
inbox = outlook.Folders(accounts[0].DeliveryStore.DisplayName)
for obj in inbox.Folders: #how to know how many new email in this dir?
    try:
        if hasattr(obj, "__str__"):
            dirName =  obj.__str__() #as some new email in this obj.

        for message in obj.items: # how to know this email is not be read ?
            subject = sender = ''
            if hasattr(message, "Subject"):
                subject = message.Subject
            if hasattr(message, "SenderName"):
                sender = message.SenderName 
            print(sender, subject)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"i:{obj.__str__()}")
```

and where can I learn win32com.mapi?
I wanna know what func can I use in mapi.

give me some info,please~
so much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for unread messages? Use `MAPIFolder.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true")` to retrieve `Items` collection with the restriction applied.

Comment: yes！thank you so much!
`unreadMsgList= obj.Items.Restrict("[Unread] = true")
for msg in unreadMsgList:
    print(msg.Subject,msg.sender)`

Comment: If the post answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!